# HTTP request using cURL works but doesn't work in Python requests

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests

I am trying to fetch a HTTP request response using cURL, which works fine. However, when I use 'requests' package in Python I am not getting any response (it just times out, no error or response returned).

My cURL code as follows:

```
curl 'http://144.126.138.12:17001/api/v0/get-posts-stateless' \
  -H 'authority: bitclout.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'origin: https://bitclout.com' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: datadome=2P0n.mJzUY2hB5B03Tc2hild-xu2AkuX~-mIgJ2VRW-j35yl3njRPJEKTAHgcxyQdxrX-E3vQnr5GSEA~DfK3nyrtPJB1M77Ndccn3BZnf; INGRESSCOOKIE=389b5e3fc60c40d6115364749da12fd0; amp_23345b=c6QQHrpE_pvlOyAXAEKiaE.QkMxWUxpRWIzMVVHWHZ4bUZ0N0piQktIS2pjRjJTMUhZNVNkOEMzWlp5ZTFmQnVEVTVOZnNoYw==..1f6htdgom.1f6htgqqm.4r.0.4r' \
  --data-raw '{"PostHashHex":"","ReaderPublicKeyBase58Check":"BC1YLiUgto51FaPyCPwf2LGGQcCo4qa3XM3KY1zAbK8jCzaDCc4bU27","OrderBy":"newest","StartTstampSecs":null,"PostContent":"","NumToFetch":400,"FetchSubcomments":false,"GetPostsForFollowFeed":false,"GetPostsForGlobalWhitelist":false,"GetPostsByClout":false,"PostsByCloutMinutesLookback":0,"AddGlobalFeedBool":false}' \
  --compressed
```

When I use -v with the cURL code then I get the following message:

> - Trying 144.126.138.12...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to 144.126.138.12 (144.126.138.12) port 17001 (#0)
>
> > POST /api/v0/get-posts-stateless HTTP/1.1
> > Host: 144.126.138.12:17001
> > Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> > authority: bitclout.com
> > sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
> > accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> > sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
> > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Mobile
> > Safari/537.36
> > content-type: application/json
> > origin: https://bitclout.com
> > sec-fetch-site: same-origin
> > sec-fetch-mode: cors
> > sec-fetch-dest: empty
> > accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
> > cookie: datadome=2P0n.mJzUY2hB5B03Tc2hild-xu2AkuX~-mIgJ2VRW-j35yl3njRPJEKTAHgcxyQdxrX-E3vQnr5GSEA~DfK3nyrtPJB1M77Ndccn3BZnf;
> > INGRESSCOOKIE=389b5e3fc60c40d6115364749da12fd0;
> > amp_23345b=c6QQHrpE_pvlOyAXAEKiaE.QkMxWUxpRWIzMVVHWHZ4bUZ0N0piQktIS2pjRjJTMUhZNVNkOEMzWlp5ZTFmQnVEVTVOZnNoYw==..1f6htdgom.1f6htgqqm.4r.0.4r
> > Content-Length: 351
>
> - upload completely sent off: 351 out of 351 bytes < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true < Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
>   Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept <
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS <
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://bitclout.com <
>   Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' < Content-Type:
>   application/json < Referrer-Policy: same-origin <
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < X-Frame-Options: DENY <
>   X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block < Date: Thu, 27 May 2021 20:21:56 GMT
>   < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> - Connection #0 to host 144.126.138.12 left intact
> - Closing connection 0

My Python code using requests as follows:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'bitclout.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://bitclout.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'datadome=2P0n.mJzUY2hB5B03Tc2hild-xu2AkuX~-mIgJ2VRW-j35yl3njRPJEKTAHgcxyQdxrX-E3vQnr5GSEA~DfK3nyrtPJB1M77Ndccn3BZnf; INGRESSCOOKIE=389b5e3fc60c40d6115364749da12fd0; amp_23345b=c6QQHrpE_pvlOyAXAEKiaE.QkMxWUxpRWIzMVVHWHZ4bUZ0N0piQktIS2pjRjJTMUhZNVNkOEMzWlp5ZTFmQnVEVTVOZnNoYw==..1f6htdgom.1f6htgqqm.4r.0.4r',
}

data = '{"PostHashHex":"","ReaderPublicKeyBase58Check":"BC1YLiUgto51FaPyCPwf2LGGQcCo4qa3XM3KY1zAbK8jCzaDCc4bU27","OrderBy":"newest","StartTstampSecs":null,"PostContent":"","NumToFetch":400,"FetchSubcomments":false,"GetPostsForFollowFeed":false,"GetPostsForGlobalWhitelist":false,"GetPostsByClout":false,"PostsByCloutMinutesLookback":0,"AddGlobalFeedBool":false}'

response = requests.post('http://144.126.138.12:17001/api/v0/get-posts-stateless', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

Why is this happening and how can I make my Python code work?

Comment: You didn't post the error message or info about the response?

Comment: @PaulBecotte There is no error. It just times out. I have also updated my question to reflect this as well.

Comment: times out and throws an exception? Or just doesn't print any output? If you add `-v` to your curl command... is it using a proxy?

Comment: @PaulBecotte it doesn't print anything. no error at all. Its not using a proxy (i guess). I have updated my answer with -v on cURL code as well.

Comment: its not _supposed_ to print anything... you're capturing the response in a variable. Try `print(response.text)`

Comment: @PaulBecotte my bad that i forgot to include the print text here but I have done that and it is the same. it is not printing anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232972/discussion-between-somdip-dey-and-paul-becotte).

Answer (score 1):

I run the exact code and get a (rather large) response after about 20 seconds.

The length of the response which is too large to post is `2,067,812` characters.

With a slower connection (i use broadband with download 2Mb per sec) that would take even longer, that is probably why you get no response or it appears to be hanging.

I have added this code and just pulled the `status_code` in place of the `text` which takes only
a few seconds to run. Try this:

```
import requests
import time

t1 = time.time()

headers = {
    'authority': 'bitclout.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://bitclout.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'datadome=2P0n.mJzUY2hB5B03Tc2hild-xu2AkuX~-mIgJ2VRW-j35yl3njRPJEKTAHgcxyQdxrX-E3vQnr5GSEA~DfK3nyrtPJB1M77Ndccn3BZnf; INGRESSCOOKIE=389b5e3fc60c40d6115364749da12fd0; amp_23345b=c6QQHrpE_pvlOyAXAEKiaE.QkMxWUxpRWIzMVVHWHZ4bUZ0N0piQktIS2pjRjJTMUhZNVNkOEMzWlp5ZTFmQnVEVTVOZnNoYw==..1f6htdgom.1f6htgqqm.4r.0.4r',
}

data = '{"PostHashHex":"","ReaderPublicKeyBase58Check":"BC1YLiUgto51FaPyCPwf2LGGQcCo4qa3XM3KY1zAbK8jCzaDCc4bU27","OrderBy":"newest","StartTstampSecs":null,"PostContent":"","NumToFetch":400,"FetchSubcomments":false,"GetPostsForFollowFeed":false,"GetPostsForGlobalWhitelist":false,"GetPostsByClout":false,"PostsByCloutMinutesLookback":0,"AddGlobalFeedBool":false}'

response = requests.post('http://144.126.138.12:17001/api/v0/get-posts-stateless', headers=headers, data=data)

t2 = time.time()

print(response.status_code)

print('time taken:', round(t2-t1, 2), 'seconds')
```

the response:

```
200
time taken: 3.93 seconds
```

Comment: Even if I change the NumToFetch variable in the data to 4 instead of 400, which is the number that specifies the amount of data to bring in, I am still getting no response back.

Comment: the "NumToFetch":4 does have an effect.  it reduces the response time singificantly for me.   from 3.93 seconds to 0.56 seconds.

Comment: i belive that you may have issues with a stateless header depending on the browser / settings etc.

Comment: I used ur exact headers but still no response from the server :(

Comment: Have you tried using a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to verify that the Python code is actually making a TCP connection and sending the HTTP request, and nothing is coming back from the server?

Comment: given that i was able to get a response with the same code, it clearly points to a settings issue of some kind at your end (and not the code). Therefore, the next step in the process would be to see if you can send data to other 'test' sites and find the error in a stepwise process from there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try data like this:

```
data = "{\"PostHashHex\":\"\",\"ReaderPublicKeyBase58Check\":\"BC1YLiUgto51FaPyCPwf2LGGQcCo4qa3XM3KY1zAbK8jCzaDCc4bU27\",\"OrderBy\":\"newest\",\"StartTstampSecs\":null,\"PostContent\":\"\",\"NumToFetch\":400,\"FetchSubcomments\":false,\"GetPostsForFollowFeed\":false,\"GetPostsForGlobalWhitelist\":false,\"GetPostsByClout\":false,\"PostsByCloutMinutesLookback\":0,\"AddGlobalFeedBool\":false}"
```

Comment: Nope. the result is same. no response back.